# Listview filter the data contained in database very slowly

Tags: android, database, listview, dictionary, filter

I'm Working an English to Persian Dictionary ...
Unfortunately, I could not using Lazzy Listview sample In my project ,
my project initially had a list and `filter` out about 50 thousand words from database , so slow typing and updating the list is occured , please Help me to use `Lazzy Listview` In my project and use a optimized filter to reduce the use of memory and increase speed ....
Tnx

this is my classes :

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView                         list;
ImageView                        clearText;
EditText                         editsearch;
Typeface                         edtSearchFont;
static String[]                  word;
static int[]                     index;
static ListViewAdapter           adapter;
static ArrayList<ListViewStruct> arrayStructList = new ArrayList<ListViewStruct>();
Context                          context;


// onCreate

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
    context = this;

    Cursor en = G.database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM English", null);
    word = new String[en.getCount()];
    index = new int[en.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    ListViewStruct wp = null;
    if (en.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            try {
                word[i] = en.getString(en.getColumnIndex("English_Word"));
                index[i] = en.getInt(en.getColumnIndex("Word_ID"));
                wp = new ListViewStruct(word[i], index[i]);
                arrayStructList.add(wp);
                i++;

            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        while (en.moveToNext());
    }
    en.close();

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arrayStructList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    edtSearchFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/listFont.ttf");
    editsearch.setTypeface(edtSearchFont);
    editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }


        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            adapter.filter(text);
        }
    });

    clearText = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.clearTextImage);

    clearText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            editsearch.setText("");

        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    menu.add(0, 1, 1, "About");
    menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Exit");

    return true;

}


//@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case 1: {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("About")
                    .setMessage("\n" + "© Copyright" + "\n" + "Hossein Tahmasebi , 2014" + "\n")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

            break;

        }
        case 2: {

            this.finish();

        }

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
};
```

}

**ListViewAdapter**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context                           mContext;
LayoutInflater                    inflater;
private List<ListViewStruct>      localWordsList;
private ArrayList<ListViewStruct> arraystructlist;
public int                        index;
Typeface                          listFont;


public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<ListViewStruct> mainWordList) {
    mContext = context;
    this.localWordsList = mainWordList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.arraystructlist = new ArrayList<ListViewStruct>();
    this.arraystructlist.addAll(mainWordList);

}


public class ViewHolder {

    TextView word;

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return localWordsList.size();
}


@Override
public ListViewStruct getItem(int position) {
    return localWordsList.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    listFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/listFont.ttf");

    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        holder.word = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.word);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.word.setText(localWordsList.get(position).getWord());
    holder.word.setTypeface(listFont);

    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, enTranslatedResultActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("index", (localWordsList.get(position).getIndex()));
            intent.putExtra("word", (localWordsList.get(position).getWord()));
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return view;
}


// Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    localWordsList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        localWordsList.addAll(arraystructlist);
    }
    else
    {
        for (ListViewStruct wp: arraystructlist)
        {
            if (wp.getWord().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).startsWith(charText))
            {
                localWordsList.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

}

ListViewStruct

```
public class ListViewStruct {
    private int    index;
    private String word;
    private String translatedWord;


    public ListViewStruct(String word, int index) {

        this.word = word;
        this.index = index;

    }


    public int getIndex() {
        return this.index;
    }


    public String getWord() {
        return this.word;
    }


    public String getPopulation() {
        return this.translatedWord;
    }
}
```

`G class` , `HelperIO` And `enTranslatedResultActivity` for show translated result word.....

If these classes are required to be here , tell me to put them ,

Thank you for your attention.....

Comment: use SimpleCursorAdapter as your data comes from an sqlite database

Comment: please edit my codes as you say , I'm a beginner

Comment: see http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Comment: did you try to use cursor adapter?it is much faster than others for this type of list

Comment: @MHP please edit my code and say how i can use cursor adapter here

Answer (score 0):

this is example of cursorAdapter(use it instead of baseAdapter) you need to pass cursor to it and don't need to put cursor in arraylist in while loop

```
public class ImageCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public ImageCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView word = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.word);
    word.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("English_Word")));
    word.setTypeface(listFont);
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, enTranslatedResultActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("index", (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Word_ID")));
        intent.putExtra("word", (cursor.getColumnIndex("English_Word")));
        context.startActivity(intent);
        }
  });
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
    bindView(convertView , context, cursor);
    return convertView ;
}
}
```

in newView do something like your getView method (without viewHolder)
and in bindView just need that set data for your view 
also you can set editText and bind it with this adapter for this set OntextchangeListener for editText then you have fast search when user typing in editText.
probably better way for better performance exist but I share everything I know